# Embedding / Antialiasing user defined font in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, embed, antialiasing

I can see many people have asked a similar question (and I have read them) but all the answers in those questions won't really help me 100%.

Basically I'm building a small app in Flash (or AIR) and I want to user to be able to change a textfield font to be whatever font they want off their computer.

If there anyway I can anti alias this font? I know about embed tags and external swf font files etc, but that doesn't help in this case as I want them to be able to whatever font they would like off their own computers.

I don't know if I can embed the font they choose at runtime or if there is some workaround for anti aliasing a system font that isn't embedded. In the end they are saving out the text as a PNG... so maybe there is some way to smooth out the text in an image?

Or am I just stuck with pixelated fonts with no anti aliasing? :(

Thanks for your help!
Jesse.

Answer (score 1):

You could relatively easily do the anti-aliasing yourself, by creating a bitmap in which you draw the text, using your non-embedded font, twice or four times as big as you want it to be, and then scaling the bitmap down to the needed dimensions, with smoothing enabled.

Comment: I think I would rather apply 50% scaling twice than 25% at one time, because bilinear filtering will average neghbour pixels, if you apply 25% scale, you will lose more details

Answer (score 0):

You must embed the font in order to use it properly. You can load swf files with embedded fonts at runtime, but this still means you need those swf files. So the answer is - you cannot let users chose fonts from their own computers to be embedded, without any special backend service.

It's possible if you upload the file to your server, build (compile) swf file with embedded font and then load it within your client. Unfortunately I think this would be too much of a work..